# JavaScript - Rotate Image to Angle Between Two Values and Re-Position Image Centre

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a gauge, I have two hardcoded values - a `min` (`0`) and `max` (`200`) and then a calculated value returned via ajax.

For simplicity, the let's say that value is `100`, I am then trying to figure out the correct angle to rotate my image to.

I know in my head it's `0` degrees (value `0` is `-90` degrees and `200` is `+90` degrees) but I can't seem to find the correct formula to calculate it programmatically.

Then, if the correct angle is returned and the image rotated, the base of the image will then be off-centre, so that will then need re-calculated too (`left` and `top` positions).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uj5n/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data = [{"count":100}]; // from ajax

    var error_rate = data[0].count;

    var max = 200;

    if (error_rate > max) {
        max = error_rate
        $('div.max-label').text(max);
    }

    $('#pointer_value').text(error_rate);

    var x = 0;
    var y = max;

    var theta = Math.atan2(-y, x);

    if (theta < 0) {
        theta += 2 * Math.PI;
     }

    var degree = theta * (180 / Math.PI); // 270 degrees - result should be 0


    var img = $('img.pointer');
    img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

});
```

**HTML**

```
<article class="widget">
    <div class="widget-inner">
        <header>
            <h1>Todays Error Rate</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="widget-body">
            <div class="widget-canvas">

                <div id="pointer_value" class="value">0</div>
                <div class="scale">
                    <div class="pointer-canvas">
                        <img class="pointer" src="https://d28q98t4icjy0h.cloudfront.net/assets/icons/geckometer-pointer.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="t-tertiary">Min Errors</div>
                    <div class="min-label">0</div>
                </div>
                <div class="max">
                    <div class="t-tertiary">Max Errors</div>
                    <div class="max-label">200</div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
div.widget-canvas div.value {
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
}

div.widget-canvas .scale {
  width: 143px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left: 27px;
  background: url(https://d28q98t4icjy0h.cloudfront.net/assets/icons-sced228de5c-269bfee7198436f43fe1f1efdf4d274c.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -343px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto 10px auto;
}

div.min {
  float: left;
}

div.min-label {
  color: #28b779;
}

div.max {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

div.max-label {
  color: #d84a38;
  text-align: right;
}

div.widget-canvas .main-stat {
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

div.widget-canvas .secondary-stat {
  font-size: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.widget-canvas .pointer-canvas {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

div.widget-canvas img.pointer {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the following:

```
// calculate angle based on proportion
var degree = 180 * error_rate / max;

// rotate pointer container but not image
var img = $('.pointer-canvas');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2uj5n/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula to transform `0 to 200` in `-90 to 90` then:

```
0 is -90 degrees
100 is 0 degrees
200 is 90 degress
```

so

```
function rotation(input) {
    return (input-100) * .9;
}
```

Comment: hmm, then that would give 90 instead of 0?

Comment: If the input is 100, then the result is (100-100) * .9 = 0. You said "For simplicity, the let's say that value is 100, (...) I know in my head it's 0 degrees (value 0 is -90 degrees and 200 is +90 degrees) (...)"

Comment: ah, I was thinking you were using the max value (200) as the param to the rotation function for some reason. I'm not sure this will work for any value though as it seems to be hardwired to work for `100` value and that's it.

Comment: Well, 100 is the value of the center, .9 is the ratio between the max input value (200) and the max value in degrees (180). You can use configurable values there: return `(input-(MAX-MIN)/2) * (180/MAX);`